# Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution' Sharepoint 2013

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, site-collection, backup, solution-deployment

My machine shutdown when I was taking the solution backup. Then I started, I coudn't deploy the solution code from visual studio saying

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': <nativehr>0x80070005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Access denied.
```

Any idea I need to recover from this error?

I am running VS local administrator.logged in to machine using spAdmin. spAdmin is having all the necessary permissions as i guess.Previous times before the sudden shutdown of the machine,this was working though.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have started visual studio using an account that has necessary permissions.

Alternatively you can try deploying using SharePoint Management She'll.

Comment: I am running VS local administrator.logged in to machine using spAdmin. spAdmin is having all the necessary permissions as i guess.Previous times before the sudden shutdown of the machine,this was working though.

Comment: try deploying using SharePoint Management She'll

Answer (score 0):

This was really misunderstood the error given by visual studio.

It was happen due to the fact that the unexpected shutdown of my machine, it affected to the ongoing process of taking site collection backup.

This was found after so many blogs read and so many user permissions changed in SharePoint. This mainly happen due to power shell command being interrupted, which caused SharePoint put the site in lock mode.

I refer below url and done the trick by setting the content db property changed as mentioned.

https://nasironline.wordpress.com/tag/we-apologize-for-any-inconvenience-but-weve-made-the-site-read-only-while-were-making-some-improvements/

http://blog.portiva.nl/2014/06/25/sharepoint-2013-site-stuck-in-read-only-mode/

Done.